# File Handling with LinkList in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, binaryfiles, file-handling, doubly-linked-list

**PROBLEM:** I am trying to write (binary writing) an object of Doubly Linked List onto File & write from it too.
I have to write object's complete contents, then load it from file, and store it into new object to re-create the list in FIFO order.
I thinking I am writing correctly, but I seriously have no idea how to load (read) it from file.

REMEMBER: I am just trying to save and read `CONTENTS` of a node, & `NOT POINTERS.`

CODE:

```
//template type BOOK class

template<class mytype>
class BOOK      
{
private:
    static int count;   //declaration of static variable to set ID for books
public:
    BOOK<mytype> *next, *prev;  //BOOK type pointers; 'next' to store address of 
next BOOK & 'prev' to store address of previous BOOK
    int ID;         //variable to store ID of a book
    string bookName;//string to store name of a book
    string author;  //string to store name of author of book
    string book_type;//string to store type of a book
    long copies;    //variable to store no. of copies a book
    long price;     //variable to store price of a book
    string status;  //to store status of a book, either its in stock or not
    dynamicQueue<string> book_queue;    //created an object of queueClass as data member of each Book

    BOOK()  //Constructor 0 argument to initialize everything
    {
        count++;    //increment counter
        ID=count;   //assign counter to ID to be ID of newly added book

        next = prev = 0;        //Initializing both pointers to 0

        bookName = "\0";
        author = "\0";
        book_type = "\0";
        copies = price = 0;
        status= "InStock";
    }

    BOOK(BOOK *n =  0, BOOK *p = 0, string book = "\0", string athr = "\0", string buk_type = "\0", long cp=0, long pr=0) //Constructor multiple arguments, to store information about a book
    {
        next = n;       //store contents of user-given value n into next
        prev = p;       //store contents of user-given value p into previous

        bookName = book;//store contents of user-given value book into bookName
        author = athr;  //store contents of user-given value athr into author
        book_type = buk_type;//store contents of user-given value buk_type into book_type
        copies = cp;    //store contents of user-given value cp into copies
        price = pr;     //store contents of user-given value pr into price
        status= "InStock";
        count++;        //increment counter
        ID=count;       //assign counter to ID to be ID of newly added book
    }
};

template <class mytype>    // declaration of
int BOOK<mytype>::count=0; // static variable to set ID for books
//--------------------
```

Main Part for Adding a new Book.

```
BookStoreDataBase<char> obj;    //created object of Doubly linked list
string Book, Author, Booktype;
long Copies=1, Price=0;
cout<<"Enter Name of Book = ";  cin>>Book;
cout<<"Enter Author = ";        cin>>Author;
cout<<"Enter Type of Book = ";  cin>>Booktype;
cout<<"Enter Number of Copies = ";  cin>>Copies;
cout<<"Enter Price (PKR) = ";   cin>>Price;

obj.addBook(Book, Author, Booktype, Copies, Price);
```

Saving function to save all data to file

```
template <class mytype>
void DoublyLinkedList<mytype>::save_data()
{
    NODE<mytype> * temp = head; //made copy of head
    fstream file;     //created new file
    file.open("mydata.txt", ios::binary | ios::out | ios::app);

    while(temp->next!=0) //Until link list end
    {
          file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), sizeof(temp));
          temp = temp - > next; //move temp to next node
    }
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), sizeof(temp)); //write again for last  
                                                              //book's data
    file.close();
}
```

*Now I have practically no idea on how to read the list from file, store contents into each node & with disturbing the saved arrangement, re-create the list in FIFO order. So I can print it later. I have practiced alot, gone to forums etc etc but not found any concrete Solution. Please help me out. Thanks in advance*

---

A sample of my effort

```
template <class mytype>
void DoublyLinkedList<mytype>::load_data()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("mydata.txt", ios::binary | ios::in);
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        NODE<mytype> *temp = new NODE<mytype>;
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), sizeof(temp));
        if(is_Empty())
        {
            head = tail = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->prev->next = temp;
            temp->next=0;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
//-------------------
```

NO COMPILE TIME ERROR.

**RUNTIME ERROR:** Unhandled exception at 0x00CD8391 in DobulyList.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to binary write a class with std::strings in it and have the string data be included in the output. Why is Book a template class?

Comment: Book class is acting like a NODE class or struct to be used with original DoublyClass (DataBase Class) to manage a single node/book.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best bet is to have a method on the BOOK class that can serialise the contents in a predefined way.

```
template<class mytype>
class BOOK      
{
private:
    //members
public:
    //more members

    ....

    bool read( istream& in );
    bool write( ostream& out );

    ....

};
```

So because you want binary - you'd need to have and int written for the ID, then size, bytes for the string (s) etc...

Then you reverse this for the read. read an int and assign to ID, then read size, read size chars and assign to the string etc...

e.g

```
//fill in template stuff I'm lazy...
bool Book::read( istream& in )
{
     size_t stringSize; //you need to think about what types you read/write
     char buffer[SomeArbitrarySize];
     file.read( ID ,sizeof(int));
     file.read( stringSize ,sizeof(size_t));
     file.read( buffer, stringSize );
     mStringMember = buffer;
     ... etc ...
}
```

then for each item in the list you delegate the call to read/write to the node. You would possibly want to write/read an entry first for the number of nodes as well.

```
template <class mytype>
void DoublyLinkedList<mytype>::load_data()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("mydata.txt", ios::binary | ios::in);
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        NODE<mytype> *temp = new NODE<mytype>;
        temp->read(file);
        if(is_Empty())
        {
            head = tail = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->prev->next = temp;
            temp->next=0;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Bro I totally couldn't understand what you just said :D
count is a static variable which will be incremented, each time a book is created in _BookStoreDatabase Class_ . & when it is incremented, I put a copy of it in book's node as its ID. So IDs of books are generated automatically. Sample:
Book ID 1 -> OOP in C++
Book ID 2 -> DataStructures in C++ 
I have also written a method in _BookStoreDataBasse Class_ to search a book by its ID #, OR by its name, OR by its author.

Comment: Ok, I was in a hurry when I posted - What I mean is that each element of the Book class probably needs to be written to the file individually in a predetermined order and then read back in the same order. I'll make the answer more readable...